# LINQ Join in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq, join

I have looked in many places, and I've seen it a couple places in C#, but nothing in VB.NET. So here is the setup. I have 3 tables. They are formatted like

```
Quiz
=========
ID
CourseID
PassingNumber

Question
==========
ID
QuizID
QuestionText

Answer
==========
ID
QuestionID
AnswerText
IsCorrect
```

I want to query them place them into an list of objects. Basically I want to do this:

```
Dim quizzes = From qui In Quiz
Where qui.CouseID = courseID (This variable is passed from a function)
Select qui.ID, qui.PassingNumber
For Each qui.ID
From que In Question
Where que.QuizID = qui.ID
Select que.ID, que.QuestionText
For Each que.ID
From ans In Answer
Where ans.QuestionID = que.ID
Select ans.AnswerText, ans.IsCorrect
```

I know the For Each should be something like a Join, but I just can't seem to quite grasp that concept. If I saw it for this, I think I would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, this question was already answered from another post.

[LINQ: "Group Join" functionality joining three tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295734/linq-group-join-functionality-joining-three-tables)

This is what I wanted and it worked brilliantly:

```
Dim orderProds = From order In cData.Orders _
      Group Join prod In cData.Products _
      On order.ProductID Equals prod.ProductID Into OrderProducts = Group

Dim customerOrderProducts = From cust In cData.Customers _
                        Group Join ordProd In orderProds _
                        On cust.CustomerID Equals ordProd.order.CustomerID Into custOrderProds = Group
```

Adapted to my code:

```
Dim qAs = From que In _dataContext.Questions _
    Group Join ans In _dataContext.Answers _
    On ans.quiestionID Equals que.ID Into QuestionAnswers = Group

Dim qQAs = From qui In _dataContext.Quizs _ (<- Microsoft's pluralization for ya')
    Group Join qA In qAs _
    On qui.ID Equals qA.que.quizID Into QuizQuestionAnswers = Group _
    Where qui.courseID = courseID
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you trying to do the most simple way would probably be used include

```
   Dim q = db.Quiz.Where(q=>q.CouseID = 
courseID).Include("Question").Include("Question.Answer").ToList()
```

Comment: That would result in all the questions and answers, but Miguel asked for specifics via an Inner Join, which is not necessary anyway.

Comment: I think he specifically asked to use joins not the where conditions and include joins only based on the foreign key

Comment: Ah, then in that case, you are correct completely. But he did not mention if he was using Linq to Entities or EF. What namespace is the `.Include` function in, I'm also sure this a lambda expression which can replace the requirement for the String expression.

Comment: I guess this is where this goes. I have a repository, and I am trying to fill the viewmodel based on a courseID value that gets passed to it.

Comment: There are multiple quizzes per course, so it would be an I<Enumerable>